# Using redux with react, why is fetching new data deletes part of my previous state?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have multiple requests happening one after the other, I handle them with actions and reducers but some of them seem to delete elements of my state when completed.

Can someone explain to me why this is the case?

Here is my reducer:

```
...
    case FETCH_BLOG:
      return { ...state, blogs: action.payload.data };
    case FETCH_ITEM_LIST:
      return { ...state.item, done: true, popular: [ ...state.popular ], nearby: [ ...state.nearby ], item: { ...state.item }, second_item: { ...state.second_item }, items: action.payload.data.item , new_item: action.payload.data.new_item, item_places: action.payload.data.item_places, stories: action.payload.data.stories };
    case FETCH_ITEM_NEARBY:
      return { ...state, nearby: action.payload.data.nearby, loading: false, count: action.payload.data.count, done: true };
    case FETCH_ITEM_NEARBY_START:
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    case FETCH_ITEM_POPULAR:
      return { ...state, popular: action.payload.data.popular };
...
```

I thought using ...state would keep the previous state and just add elements to it but it seems like it overrides it somehow.

I call my actions in this order, and I can see that after some actions are finished, part of my previous state is deleted.

```
    this.props.itemNearbyFetch();
    this.props.itemPopularFetch();
    this.props.itemListFetch();
    this.props.blogFetch();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `FETCH_ITEM_LIST` action you are only spreading the item into state, which would get rid of any attributes of the state object and replace with whatever attributes your `item` has. I think you are misunderstanding how the spread operator works.

What you want to do is something like

```
case FETCH_ITEM_LIST:
  return { ...state, 
       done: true, 
       items: action.payload.data.items, 
       new_item: action.payload.data.new_item, 
       item_places: action.payload.data.item_places, 
       stories: action.payload.data.stories 
  };
```

In the previous example you would now have anything that was previously on state like `popular` and `nearby` be copied, `stories, items, and item_places` from the payload data are returned to the new state.

doing `item:{...state.item}` is redundant as it is handled when you do `{...state, ...}`

Comment: oh well, I didn't notice I was using ...state.item instead of simply ...state. That fixed it, thank you for pointing it out!